# Inavlid react Native permission ios.PERMISSION.CAMERA

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-permissions

I am using [react-native-qr-code-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner) to add QR scanner functionality in my app. I followed all the instaruction ther & everything works fine on android but when i build my app on ios app is not able to find the `RNPermissions` library so i manually linked it as suggested on it README. Linked error is now gone and i am getting Invali RMPermission `ios.PERMISSION.CAMERA should be one of()`. The error is described on the github page of [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#%EF%B8%8F-if-you-encounter-the-error-invalid-rnpermission-x-should-be-one-of-) README PAGE & steps to solve it.
 it says

> Check that you linked at least one permission handler.

I cannot add permission handler as described there to Podfile as it aslo  installs the `React(0.11.0)` verison automatically (but this is not required ) as i already have newest react. what is the way to solve this?

[!]

When i run `pod install` after adding

```
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
```

i  get

```
Unable to find a specification for `RNPermissions` depended upon by `Permission-Camera`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Answer (score 7):

I've gotten the issue `ios.PERMISSION.CAMERA should be one of()` as well, use the following command in podfile will solve your issue.

```
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
```

Comment: Not resolving ios.PERMISSION.CAMERA should be one of() error with above code

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to do the following changes in **podfile** :

**add :modular_header => false**

```
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

add permissions for usage of camera for qrcode scanning:

```
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera.podspec"
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: After editing podfile do I need to pod install or normal run ?

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the file path, it should be like "/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec".

```
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone/Permission-Microphone.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
```